# How to include ActionView::Helpers in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionviewhelper

Following is my code.

```
class PropertyDetailsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers

  #Action methods.
end
```

But the above code is throwing following error when I try to run.

```
Module::DelegationError (ActionView::Helpers::ControllerHelper#action_name delegated to controller.action_name, but controller is nil:
```

Any Suggestions.

**UPDATE**
Is that true if we use params and session we cant include ActionView::Helpers

Reference: http://alphahydrae.com/2013/06/rails-3-rendering-views-outside-a-controller/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to `require 'action_view'`